# reference custom function in apply R

Tags: r

I have an N x 2 matrix called mat.

```
mat <- cbind(c(2:4), c(.5, 1, 1.5))
colnames(mat) <- c('x2', 'x3')
```

I created a function called calcCDF in R. This function requires 3 inputs x1, x2, and x3. x1 defaults to 100000. The actual calcCDF function is more complicated. The one shown below is just to illustrate the point.

```
calcCDF <- function(x1=100000, x2, x3){
cdf <- x1 + x2 * x3
return(cdf)
}
```

`calcCDF(x2=2, x3=0.5)` returns the value 100001

I would like x2 and x3 to be populated with the first and second columns of mat respectively and apply the function to each row of mat so that I get back a vector of length N.

I tried `apply(mat, 1, calcCDF(x2=mat[1], x3=mat[2]))` but get an error stating Error: unexpected ']'.

Comment: Hard saying w/out example, but try this `apply(mat, 1,calcCDF,x2= mat[1],x3 = mat[2])`

Comment: dont forget to index columns with mat[, i] @BrianDavis. But yeah, please post a reproducible example

Comment: still get the same error message when trying @BrianDavis suggestion.

Comment: You don't need `apply` for that; just use `calcCDF(x2=mat[,1], x3=mat[,2])`.

Comment: @Ista, I get one number rather than a vector of length N. It is also accompanied with a warning message.

Comment: `mat <- cbind(x2 = 2:4, x3 = c(.5, 1, 1.5)); calcCDF <- function(x1=100000, x2, x3){x1 + x2 * x3}; calcCDF(x2 = mat[, 1], x3 = mat[, 2])` produces three numbers as expected. You're going to have to show me what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `apply()` with your customised function `calcCDF`, this is how you can use

```
 apply(mat, 1, function(y) calcCDF(x2 = y[1], x3 = y[2]))
```

OR

```
 apply(mat, 1, function(x) calcCDF(x2 = x["x2"], x3 = x["x3"]))
```